# NullPointerException in Saxon9 namespace LRUCache

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

An XSLT transformation in our production system (Java7 runtime) fails every now and then with the NullPointerException provided below.
As far as I understand from the Saxon9 source code, the LRUCache class is a static class member in the AnyURIValue class.
I did some research on this and read that this could be due to concurrency and non-sychronized calls on the 
underlying LinkedHashMap, which would explain that the problem seems to appear at random points in time for us.

```
The [java.lang.NullPointerException] occurred during XSLT transformation:  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tibco.plugin.xml.XMLTransformActivity.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.plugin.Activity.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.TaskImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.Job.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.Job.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.JobDispatcher$JobCourier.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.JobDispatcher$JobCourier.run(Unknown Source)
caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry.recordRemoval(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.removeEntryForKey(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.addEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.sort.LRUCache.put(LRUCache.java:47)
    at net.sf.saxon.value.AnyURIValue.isValidURI(AnyURIValue.java:103)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Namespace.checkPrefixAndUri(Namespace.java:184)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Namespace.processLeavingTail(Namespace.java:144)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:399)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:94)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:298)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:175)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:343)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.defaultAction(ApplyTemplates.java:376)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:331)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:1735)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1559)
    at com.tibco.plugin.xml.XMLTransformActivity.new(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.plugin.xml.XMLTransformActivity.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.plugin.Activity.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.TaskImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.Job.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.Job.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.JobDispatcher$JobCourier.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.JobDispatcher$JobCourier.run(Unknown Source)
```

- Did anyone experience the same issue with Saxon9 already?
- What is the best way to attempt to reproduce the issue in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon9 is not one release but a sequence of 6 major releases (9.0 to 9.5) and many more maintenance releases issued over a period of about 7 years. You need to be more precise about which version you are using.

There have been a couple of fixes to problems involving the LRUCache over the years, for example

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/1481
https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/1619

Athough neither of these describes a NullPointerException as the observed symptom, they could reflect the same underlying cause.

The Saxon 9.5 code uses a ConcurrentHashMap in cases where it is needed, and the AnyURIValue class no longer uses an LRUCache.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! From the net.sf.saxon.Version class I can see the following Saxon9 version information:
VERSION = "9.0.0.2"
BUILD = "113012"
RELEASE_DATE = "2007-11-30"

This version of Saxon9 is shipped with the product we are using in the company. Out of legal reasons we probably cannot
just upgrade the Saxon version ourselves, but I will request that from the supplier. As an intermediate solution I will
replace the XSLT 2.0 elements with XSLT 1.0 elements and use the products inbuilt XSLT 1.0 engine.

Comment: I don't think there are legal reasons, but there are certainly technical reasons; without knowing in detail whether Tibco has dependencies on Saxon "internal" interfaces, and without access to a comprehensive test suite, changing the version of Saxon used by Tibco would be highly inadvisable. Push them to move forward!

Answer (score 0):

Reproduced the behaviour, it seems to be a concurrency issue in Saxon9's namespace LRUCache. The error
happens for the put aswell as for the get operation on the cache. Below code simulates the problem.
The LRUCache is a static class member in Saxon's AnyURIValue.class and the access to the underlying 
LinkedHashMap is not synchronized.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {

private static final int NTHREDS = 100;

private static final int EXECUTION_COUNT = 10000;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);
    for (int i = 0; i < EXECUTION_COUNT; i++) {
        Runnable worker = new TestRunnable(i);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
}



import net.sf.saxon.sort.LRUCache;

public class TestRunnable implements Runnable {

private static LRUCache cache = new LRUCache(20); // The LRUCache is a static member in Saxon's AnyURIValue.class!

private int number;

public TestRunnable(int number){
    this.number = number;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    /**
     *  Access elements in ascending order to trigger the call to LinkedHashMap$Entry.remove;  
     */
    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
        cache.get(new Integer(i));
    }

    /**
     *  Add the new element to the cache. 
     *  As soon as the cacheSize exceeds 20, the cache is starting to remove the last accessed element.
     */
    cache.put(new Integer(number), new Integer(number));

}
}
```